# Using AND with craft.entries()

Tags: entries, conditional, params

I'm trying to return entries based on some criteria. I exclude entries with a given value like this:

```
{% set someEntries = craft.entries({
    level: 1,
    id: '1,2,3,4,5',
    myOtherField: 'not blue'
}) %}
```

But it doesn't work if I try to exclude by multiple values:

```
{% set someEntries = craft.entries({
    level: 1,
    id: '1,2,3,4,5',
    myOtherField: 'not blue and not green'
}) %}
```

It's not in [the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) and I've tried a few different syntax but had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
{% set someEntries = craft.entries({
    level: 1,
    id: '1,2,3,4,5',
    myOtherField: 'and, not blue, not green'
}) %}
```